# How to lock an array from audio processing for analysis

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, locking, nsmutablearray

In my app I'm doing some audio processing.
In the for loop of the audio buffer, there is a NSMutable array. The loop is called a huge number of time every second (depending on the buffer size).
As an example :

```
@autoreleasepool
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.mDataByteSize / 2; ++i )
    {
        if ( samples[i] > trig)
        {
            [self.k_Array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:k]];

            // other stuff

        }
    }
}
```

Then, every second, I'm calling a function for other processing.

```
- (void)realtimeUpdate:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
// Create a copy of the array
NSMutableArray *k_ArrayCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:k_Array]; // CRASH with EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1 error

//do some stuff with k_ArrayCopy
}
```

I sometime receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error because, I think, a locking problem of the array.
I spent a lot of time trying to get information on queues, locking, working copies, etc... but I'm lost on this specific case.
My questions :

1. do I have to use atomic or nonatomic for `k_array` ?
2. do I have to use a `dispatch_sync` function ? If so, where exactly ?
3. should the `realtimeUpdate` function be called on background ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why you not synchronize your code while inserting values in array? Or why you not select any way for thread safe mechanism ?

Comment: i think dispatch_sync doing well and good job... it hard to say where you need to use it in to give sort of code and discription

Comment: I have tried a lot of different things on my own. I have never managed to get a stable code...I'm quite new on iOS dev, that's why I'm asking for help for this specific purpose.

Comment: Just wondering, what sort of stuff you're doing with the array every second? There is a good chance that you can move this "stuff" to *right after* the array is updated (ie adding new objects). That way you totally avoid asynchronous code, and thus all the problems.

Comment: I could try, but I'm a bit sceptic. In my mind, it is always better to do as less work as possible after the for loop. But I might be wrong ! I'll give a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dispatch queue that will solve problem

//create queue instance variable

dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create("com.safearrayaccess.samplequeue", NULL);

//1.

```
 @autoreleasepool
    {
        for ( int i = 0; i < tempBuffer.mDataByteSize / 2; ++i )
        {
            if ( samples[i] > trig)
            {
               dispatch_async(q, ^{ 
                //queue block
                [self.k_Array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:k]];

                });

                // other stuff NOTE: if its operation on array do it in queue block only

            }
        }
    }
```

//2.

```
 - (void)realtimeUpdate:(NSTimer*)theTimer
  {
    // Create a copy of the array
    __block NSMutableArray *k_ArrayCopy;//when you use any variable inside block add __block before it

    dispatch_async(q, ^{
            //queue block
            k_ArrayCopy = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:k_Array]; 
        });

        //do some stuff with k_ArrayCopy
    }
```

Now your add and read array operation are on same queue and it will not conflict..
For more details in using dispatch queue go through apples Grand Central Dispatch doc

Other way of doing this is use NSConditonLock

Comment: thanks for your help. I don't really understand why, but this does not work at all. The array seems to have a totally erratic behavior that I can't figure out...

Comment: try dispatch dispatch_sync instead of dispatch_async

Comment: Ok, the erratic behavior disappeared with dispatch_sync. Now I have to wait and see if it crashes. I'll let you know. Btw, I had a look at the NSCondition method (which I didn't know), that could be solution as well. Thanks.